# draw a cursor for a controller using MFC

Tags: mfc, mouseevent, ondraw

I'm writing a MFC program that has a mouse-like controller connected.

The controller itself has callback function that I can get the position of it, but I want to draw a cursor for this controller that I can see where it is in the window.

There is a deviceclass that represents the controller. I new a device object in myCView class.

But I have no idea how can I keep updating the controller's position to the OnDraw() function to show its position when it is moving around.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you get a new cursor position save its x,y position in view member variables and call the view's Invalidate function. This will cause OnDraw to be called. Use the x,y in OnDraw to draw the cursor.